# guard let found nil

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type, guard

I am new to guard let patterns. How come my app crashes when `selectedRooms.text` is `nil` instead of doing the return part? And why is `rooms` of optional type when I know that `numberOfRooms` is not `nil`?

```
guard let numberOfRooms = selectedRooms.text else {
    return selectedRooms.placeholder = "type something"
    }
let rooms = Int(numberOfRooms)
x = Int(ceil(sqrt(Double(rooms!)))) //found nil value
```

Comment: Looks like `numberOfRooms` is `nil`, probably should ask check that as well

Comment: It is nil. And I expect return part to be triggered and nothing else

Comment: Sorry, I meant `rooms` is `nil`, the result of `Int(numberOfRooms)` is returning a nil, probably because `numberOfRooms` is empty or just not a number

Comment: What is the value of `numberOfRooms`? `Int(numberOfRooms)` will return `nil` when the `String` is not getting converted into `Int` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedRooms.text` cannot return `nil`.

A `UITextField` and `UITextView` always returns a `String` value. An empty `String` (`""`) is returned if there is no text in the `UITextField and UITextView`. That's the reason `else` part is not executing and `rooms` value is `nil`.

Now, in the below statement you're force-unwrapping(`!`) the `rooms`.

```
x = Int(ceil(sqrt(Double(rooms!))))
```

But, since the `rooms` is `nil`, so forcefully unwrapping it is throwing *runtime exception*.

**Solution:**

You need to add an empty check as well for the `else` part to take effect, i.e.

```
guard let numberOfRooms = selectedRooms.text, !numberOfRooms.isEmpty else { //here...
    return selectedRooms.placeholder = "type something"
}
```

Comment: It worked! Does this comma sign mean "AND" logic? And what is the purpose of exclamation mark in `!numberOfRooms.isEmpty`?

Comment: @AnatolyRudenko comma in `if/gaurd` statements is same as `&&`. `!` means "NOT".

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let numberOfRooms = selectedRooms.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines), !numberOfRooms.isEmpty else {
    return selectedRooms.placeholder = "type something"
}
if let rooms = Int(numberOfRooms) {
    x = Int(ceil(sqrt(rooms)))
}
```

you don't want to force unwrap value of numberOfRooms, you can use by checking if let